# Vectorized replace multiple fixed position characters in a string with str_sub

Tags: r, stringr

I would like to replace every 5th character in a single string with *. Here's a MWE:

```
x <- "Mary had a little lamb."
pos <- c(5, 10, 15, 20)
```

I would like the output to be:

```
[1] "Mary*had * lit*le l*amb."
```

`string::sub_str()` can identify the characters at those positions:

```
> stringr::str_sub(string = x, start = pos, end = pos)
[1] " " "a" "t" "a"
```

It doesn't work to replace them, however, since `sub_str()` expects the *string* parameter to be a vector of the same length as the *start* and *end* parameters. Not finding that, it recycles *string* to match the length of *start*/*end* and makes one replacement per element:

```
> stringr::str_sub(string = x, start = pos, end = pos) <- "*"
> x
[1] "Mary*had a little lamb." "Mary had * little lamb."
[3] "Mary had a lit*le lamb." "Mary had a little l*mb."
```

Any ideas on how to get the desired output simply, with or without `stringr:sub_str()`, but preferably without a for loop?

Comment: That's not working for me (maybe you're using shortcut notation that I'm not following) but breaking it up works: `y <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]];`  `y[pos] <- "*";` `paste0(y, collapse = "")`

Comment: `paste(replace(unlist(strsplit(x, "")), pos, "*"), collapse = "")`

Comment: Your approach should be as follows: generate a regex pattern from your positions, then run `gsub`

Comment: I was hoping that stringr would save me from regex for something quite simple like this.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = function(x, pos, rep = "*"){
    tmp = x
    for (i in pos) {
        substr(tmp, i, i) = rep
    }
    tmp
}
foo(x, pos)
#[1] "Mary*had * lit*le l*mb."
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do it without a function / for-loop. Will make that more explicit.